# How to get the first 2 digits of a value passed from main in C?

Tags: c

My program asks the user for a year like 2056. So in main, I use scanf.

However, I have a function which requires the first 2 digits of this value only.

I've tried using another scanf inside the function itself scanf("%2d"...) but then I can't have the other scanf in main for my other functions.

So how can I do this?

Comment: What didn't work with your `scanf` ?

Comment: Because it requires the input to be submitted twice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
int year = 2056;
int firstPart = year / 100;
```

Answer (score 3):

How about just divide the year number by 100?

```
int year, first_two_digits;
scanf("%d",&year);
first_two_digits = year / 100;
```

I wonder how your program **should** behave after year 10000.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, I would just read the year and extract the first two digits:

```
int year;
scanf("%4d", &year); // assuming a four digit year
int first_two_digits = year / 100;
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar question - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120459/how-to-find-the-first-and-last-n-2-digits-from-an-n-digit-number

In your case, if it is always a `4`-digit number and you always need the first `2`-digits, then as others suggested `X/100` would be the best thing to do.

But if you need `n/2`-digits from an `n`-digit integer, say `X`, then you may have to use the following:

```
first n/2 digit (for even value of n) = X / 10^(n/2)  
first n/2 digit (for odd value of n)  = X / 10^((n+1)/2) 

last n/2 digit (for even value of n) = X - [first n/2 digit * pow(10, n/2)] 
last n/2 digit (for odd value of n)  = X - [first n/2 digit * pow(10, (n+1)/2)]
```

The following may be an overkill, but you may be looking for something like this!

```
int getn(int num)
{
        return (int) log10(num) + 1;
}

void gethalfs(int num, int * first, int * last)
{
        int n, po;

        if (num == 0) return;

        n = getn(num);
        /* Here you can calculate the value of po based on whether n is even or odd */
        po = (int) pow(10, n/2);

        *first = num / po;
        *last  = num - *first * po;

        return;
}
```

In order to get the number of digits in a given integer i.e. `n` in the above case, you may look at the following possible methods - [count number of digits - which method is most efficient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721042/count-number-of-digits-which-method-is-most-efficient)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

using separate variable to get the first two digits that is first2digits=year/100;

Answer (score 1):

You can get the first 2 digits of any number by using the flowing :

`INT(X*10^(-INT(LOG(X))+1))`

for Example :

- `X = 0.005432` then `Log(X) = -2.265` and `Int(Log(x)) = -3`  . So, `10^(-int(log(x))+1) = 10^4 = 10000`. Finally , `int(X * 10000 ) = 54` which are the first 2 digits.
- `X = 3.45` then `Log(X) =0.53` and `Int(Log(x)) = 0 So, 10^(-int(log(x))+1) = 10^1 = 10`. Finally, `int(X * 10 ) = 34` which are the first 2 digits.
- `X = 3543.45`then `Log(X) =3.459` and `Int(Log(x)) = 3`  So, `10^(-int(log(x))+1) = 10^-2 = 0.01`. Finally , `int(X * 10 ) = 35` which are the first 2 digits.