# Unable to get correct output from a function in C++

Tags: c++

I hope the code is self explanatory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int digits(int inp); //Prototyping correct?

int main()
{
    cout << digits(10);//I intend to have a cin statement here
                       //Set to a constant for checking, getting 24683872. Expected 2.
}

int digits(int inp)
{
    float a = 10;
    int i = 1;
    int n;
    int m_d = 1 ;
    while (m_d >= 1) //Keeps dividing by higher powers of 10 to find digits.
    {
        n = int(pow(a, i));
        m_d = inp / n;
        i++;
    }
    cout << (i-1);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: There is a very clear answer at  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10886429/434551.

Comment: The problem here is that your digits function doesn't return anything - the function prints `2` and then main appends a random integer. Instead of `cout`, at the end of the function, `return i - 1`;. This isn't a duplicate - you should however receive a compiler warning.

Comment: @StuartLC: Exactly what I was missing. Stupid, I know. Thanks a lot!