# Converting numbers to base 10 with C++

Tags: c++

This isn't returning any answer at all when I run it. I can't quite figure out why. Basically I need to multiply each digit of a given number by its base raised to the degree equal to the number of digits. the power decrements each time it runs. Or it should, anyway. It doesnt.

```
int num, sum, base;
sum = 0;
cout << "num";
cin >> num;
cout << "base";
cin >> base;

int power = 0;

while (num > 0)
{
    power++;
    num = num/10;
}
return power;
sum = 0 ;
while (num > 0);
{
    sum = (num%10)*(pow(base, power));
    num = num/10;
    power--;


}
sum += sum;

cout << sum;
```

Comment: You are returning `power`. If this is your main method you are exiting at that point. Either way everything after it is [dead code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code).

Comment: Ah, okay. I fixed that. Now it prints out an answer, it's just the wrong one. Progress. Thanks. Any ideas as to why it's giving me the wrong answer?

Comment: @BryanCoxwell what answer is it giving?

Comment: Now it should print `0` because num is already `0` when the second loop starts, so that loop is never entered. You should copy `num` in advance and use the copy for one of your loops.

Comment: Please compile with warnings enabled.  it would have told you about 'unreachable code'...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create char array of integer using digits as size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974382/create-char-array-of-integer-using-digits-as-size)

Comment: wait what?  I didn't want to close as a dupe of _that_!  I misclicked :(

Comment: `num` is never restored to its original value.  If you fix that, then the second loop will spin indefinitely because of that `;`.

Comment: Post the entire code.  I can't tell if this is a separate function or part of `main`.

Comment: Looks like you don't understand the algorithm.  Using pen and paper, write the steps (in your language, not C++) to perform the requirements.  Run through them and modify as necessary.  When you have the algorithm working, translate the algorithm to C++.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your code, it looks like you have a rogue `return` statement in the middle of your function.  At least I'm assuming its a function as you don't have a proper function definition in your code.

Remove it and try again!

```
return power; <-- right here your function will return and no code underneath will be executed
sum = 0 ;
while (num > 0);
{
    sum = (num%10)*(pow(base, power));
    num = num/10;
    power--;
}
sum += sum;

cout << sum;
```

Comment: Dunno -- to me the return looks the same color blue as the rest of the code.  But then, I'm color-blind.