# How to count the number of digits in numbers in different bases?

Tags: python, c, algorithm, radix

I'm working with numbers in different bases (base-10, base-8, base-16, etc). I'm trying to count the number of characters in each number.

Example

> Number: `ABCDEF`
>
> Number of digits: *6*

I know about the method based on logarithms but I'm facing some problems.

1. [This Python script](http://pastebin.com/cE0wVqiB) outputs that it failed to calculate the number of digits correctly in 3,969 numbers out of 1,000,000.
2. I think the method that uses logarithms could be rather slow

Links:

- [This C program](http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/digits-count) must be very slow (what if I have a very great number?). It also can't deal with numbers in different bases (for example, base-16).
- Not a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721042/count-number-of-digits-which-method-is-most-efficient) as there the OP was asking only about base-10

---

**Edit:** certainly I can calculate the length of a string but what interests me most, is if it is possible to do the calculation *without convention to string*. I'd want to know the algorithm that could help to do it knowing just the *source-base* and *the base to convert to*.

**Edit2:** *source-base* is *base-10* and *the base to convert to* can be any other base.

---

How can we calculate the number of digits in numbers in different bases?

If I know the number in base-10, how do I calculate the number of digits in the same number converted to base-16 (base-8, etc) *without performing the conversion*?

*Note*: some Python or C code will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Just an idea before writting you a whole answer, should a method like that satisfy you : find the power n needed to have for example 16^n > your_number > 16^n , because then the number of digit should be something like n...

Comment: Are you asking us how to debug your Python script?

Comment: @EmmanuelJay, I think any method that's fast enough would suit.

Comment: @abarnert, no, I think I can manage with this myself. This script was made to test the method that uses logarithms.

Comment: @vib, oh, yes, I forgot to mention that `source_base` is base-10, oops, editing now...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Logarithms shouldn't really be slow. And you can easily calculate logarithms to any base by this formula: `logBaseN(x)=logBaseA(x)/logBaseA(N)` - you can use `ln`(Base e = 2.718...) or `logBase10` or whatever you have. So you don't really need a program, a formular should do it:

```
num_digets(N, base) = 1 + floor(log(N) / log(base))
```

where `N` is your number and `base` the base you want that number in.

For more explanation take a look here:
http://www.mathpath.org/concepts/Num/numdigits.htm

Comment: Google managed to hide this link from me, gonna investigate it now

Comment: Thanks. And i guess n = 0 will be a special case?

Comment: @MattiasWadman Yes, of course. That would be `1` in all bases. You would also need to take care of negative numbers, if that is an issue for you (and decide what is the sensible return value in your case - number of digits would be identical for `N` and `-N`, but for display you might want to add an additional character for the `-`).

Comment: This does not work in practice as shown below.

Answer (score 2):

Note your `NumToStr()` function in your Python code is incorrect due to an off-by-one in your base, it should be:

```
def NumToStr(num):
    str=''
    while num:
            str+=alpha[(num)%base]
            num=(num)/base
    return ''.join(list(reversed(str)))
```

Note that checking that this function returns the correct result would have found the error (for example, use `alpha="0123456789"`).

With this fix we get the correct number of digits using the given formula:

```
nDigits = int(ceil(log(nmb, base)))
```

*except* for exact powers of the base (`base**0`, `base**1`, `base**2`, etc...) where it is exactly one less than what it should be. This can be fixed by changing the forumla slightly to:

```
nDigits = 1 + floor(log(nmb, base))
```

Note that even this seems to fail for some inputs (for example converting from base-10 to base-10 it incorrectly says 3 digits for 1000 and 6 digits for 1000000). This seems to be due to the inherent inprecision of floats, for example:

```
print floor(log(1000, 10))
```

outputs `2` instead of the expected `3`.

Concerning your mention about performance, I would not worry about performance issues for such trivial code until you've done profiling/benchmarking that shows it to be an issue. For example, your "very slow" C code would only take at most 38 divisions by 10 for a 128-bit number. If you need better performance than this then you would run into the same issue with any trivial method mentioned here. Fastest thing I can think of would be a custom `log()` function using a combination of lookup table and linear interpolation but you would have to be careful about the resulting precision.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question. When you say your initial number is in base b1, does it mean you have a representation of it as a string in base b1 ? Maybe you want to construct some table which tells you which number in base b1 correspond to b2, b2^2, b2^3, ... and then compare your number to these numbers to see where it fits.

Otherwise I would go with the algorithm you mentioned, that can easily adopted to any base.

Input : your integer x, the base b2 you want to count the digits in.

```
int number_of_digits (int x, int b2) {
    int n = 0;
    while (x >0) {
        x/=b2;
        n++;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Both methods are only linear in n.

**EDIT** : If you want to be faster, you can implement this as a binary search. Then you can get O(log(n)).

Answer (score 1):

This problem is a little more delicate than suggested by the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29847712/1089161):

```py
>>> num_digets(1000, 10)  # there are 4 digits
3
>>> [num_digets(1000**i,10)%3 for i in range(1,10)]  # these should all be 1
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

def ndigits(N, b):
    if b < 2:
        raise ValueError('base must be integer greater than 1')
    n = abs(N)
    if n < b:
        return 1
    if b == 2:
        return n.bit_length()
    d = math.floor(math.log10(n)/math.log10(b))
    b_ = b**d
    while b_ <= n:  # this will iterate 0, 1 or 2 times
        d += 1
        b_ *= b
    return d

>>> [ndigits(1000**i,10)%3 for i in range(1,10)]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

The reason this requires extra care is that `math.log(1000**i)/math.log(10)` is a little smaller than the expected floating integer:

```py
import math
>>> math.log(1000)/math.log(10)
2.9999999999999996
```

If you use `math.log10` in base 10 it will work as expected, but then it will fail for other bases, like 125 in base 5. Here is a small set of tests for whatever formula you use:

```py
    assert ndigits(2, 2) == 2
    assert ndigits(2**48 - 1, 2) == 48
    assert ndigits(1000, 10) == 4
    assert ndigits(125, 5) == 4
    assert ndigits(100, 16) == 2
```

SymPy has a function `integer_log` that can be used to calculate that exact value so the answer is `1 + integer_log(n, b)[0]`. It is not complicated but it is slower than the direct use of `math.log` to do the calculation.

Comment: (I don't understand `If you care are`.) (You might plant a hyperlink to [kratenko's answer](/a/29847712/3789665) to not have your readers wonder whence `num_digets()`.)