# C: Safe to Calculate Number of Digits in Integer (N) of Base (b) Using Logarithmic Functions

Tags: c, logarithm

Given the formula:

`NUM_DIGITS_IN_N_FOR_BASE_B = 1 + floor(ln(abs(N)) / ln(b))`

such that `b` is a base between 2 and 36 and `N` is of type int.

According to this post [post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29847504/how-to-count-the-number-of-digits-in-numbers-in-different-bases) it seems okay to assume that the value returned for the range of all integers `[INT_MIN, INT_MAX]` would work with no round-off or overflow error. I am a bit skeptical about this. My skepticism comes from a recent post of mine @[post 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/120095/c-itoa-implementation/120363#120363). If using the mathematical definition is not "safe" in a computer program, is there another trick to use to compute the number of digits in a number N given a base b?

Comment: It is not safe, as of the standard. I'd also suspect rounding errors. Better use an integer algorithm; note you likely don't need the exact logarithm, but an integer result. The basic idea is to find the MSbit.

Comment: @user3386109 One could add special cases for INT_MIN or 0 in a very trivial manner.

Comment: @user3386109 nice, which is what I thought would happen. Now the question remains.What is the best way to calculate the number of digits in a base b number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it safe to calculate the number of digits in an integer `N` in base
>   `b` using logarithmic functions?

No absolutely not, due to rounding errors. Specifically, the risk is that `log(N)/log(b)` will be slightly less than the exact value. This is most likely to occur when `N` is an exact multiple of `b`.

> How does one count the number of digits in an integer `N` in base `b`?

Divide `N` by `b` in a loop until `N` is zero. See the `countDigits` function in the code below. Handling values of `N <= 0` is left as an exercise for the reader.

---

For example, consider the following code

```
int countDigits( int N, int b )
{
    int count;
    for ( count = 0; N; count++ )
        N /= b;
    return count;
}

int main( void )
{
    int N, b;
    if ( scanf( "%d %d", &N, &b ) != 2 )
        return 1;

    printf( "log(%3d) = %.50lf\n", N, log(N) );
    printf( "log(%3d) = %.50lf\n", b, log(b) );
    printf( "ratio    = %.50lf\n", log(N)/log(b) );
    printf( "expected = %d\n", countDigits(N, b) );
    double digits = 1 + floor(log(N) / log(b));
    printf( "computed = %lf\n", digits );
}
```

If the user enters 243 for N, and 3 for b, the output is

```
log(243) = 5.49306144334054824440727315959520637989044189453125
log(  3) = 1.09861228866810978210821758693782612681388854980469
ratio    = 4.99999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375
expected = 6
computed = 5.000000
```

The expected number of digits is 6 since 243<sub>10</sub> = 100000<sub>3</sub>. The problem with the logarithm method is that either `log(243)` is slightly too small or `log(3)` is slightly too large, resulting in a ratio that is just below `5` when it should be exactly `5`.

Answer (score 2):

[@user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35587873/2410359) well answered the first part of the post.

For the 2nd part:

> is there another trick to use to compute the number of digits in a number N 
>   given a base b.?

```
// Works for all `N` including `0`, `INT_MIN`
int num_digs = 1;
int T = N;
while (T /= b) num_digs++;
```

This calculates the number of *digits*. Does not count a sign character.

Comment: I wish I could select to posts as answers.